# default directory for create and upload file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

how I can change in cakephp the default directory where the files are created,for example with the function:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'example');
fclose($fp);
```

In cakephp when I do this,files are created by default in webroot, I am interested in change this folder for all created files, I'm not interested in changing it every time I create a file.

So How I change this default directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the path from the webroot `/path/to/the/folder/`

And in order to do what you want you could define a constant when CakePHP initializes with the path to the specific folder, like this:

```
define("MY_FILES", "/path/to/the/new/folder");
```

And when you use fopen, you can do this:

```
$fp = fopen(MY_FILES.'data.txt', 'w');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default constant

`$folder_url = WWW_ROOT.$folder;`

OR

`$path = getcwd();`

```
$file_path = $path.'/file.'/'.file_name.txt;

chmod($file_path, 0777);
$xmlFile = fopen($file_path, 'w');
```